# How do I use a regex pattern in VBS to match commas not preceded or followed by a line feed or carriage return?

Tags: regex, regex-group

As I understand regular expressions, I think this pattern should work in VBS to pick up commas in a string that are preceded or followed by a line feed or carriage return as submatch 0 or submatch 1 (one of the first two pattern groups):

```
oRe.Pattern = "(,[\n\r])|([\n\r],)|(.{2},.{2})"
```

However, in the string excerpt below, submatch 2 (third pattern group) is picking up the commas , each of which is preceded by a carriage return:
    [I want these commas ignored](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDu99.png)

Here's the code from the picture:

```
SELECT
 di.QuestionSetID AS SectionID
,di.ScoreNBR AS SectionLowestTopBoxNBR
,di.AveragePercentileNBR AS SectionTopBoxPercentileRankNBR 
,qdate.QuarterStartDTS AS SectionStartDTS 
FROM NRCPicker.PatientSatisfaction.DimensionPercentile AS di
INNER JOIN (
```

Can anyone see why these commas are being picked up as submatch 2?

I based my pattern on this article: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html. I also used regex101.com in developing and testing this pattern.

I am using VBS to parse fields from a SQL script by creating an array using split(string, ","). In some cases, there are composite fields that include commas within them. I don't want to split on those commas, so I am replacing those commas with a space before I perform the split operation. The result of my regex pattern then would be to pick up only those commas not preceded or followed by a carriage return/line feed and replace them with a space.

Hopefully this is a better illustration of what I'm trying to do:

Here's a sample of my VBscript:

```
SQLScript = "SELECT
 di.QuestionSetID AS SectionID
,di.ScoreNBR AS Section,LowestTopBoxNBR
,di.AveragePercentileNBR AS SectionTopBoxPercentileRankNBR 
,qdate.Quarter,StartDTS AS Section,StartDTS 
FROM NRCPicker.PatientSatisfaction.DimensionPercentile AS di
INNER JOIN ("
oRe.Pattern = "(,[\n\r])|([\n\r],)|(.{2},.{2})" 
oLoadFields = oRe.Replace(SQLScript, "$1$2$3")
```

Expected output (commas replaced with a space only when not at the beginning or end of a line):

```
oLoadFields = "SELECT
 di.QuestionSetID AS SectionID
,di.ScoreNBR AS Section LowestTopBoxNBR
,di.AveragePercentileNBR AS SectionTopBoxPercentileRankNBR 
,qdate.Quarter StartDTS AS Section StartDTS 
FROM NRCPicker.PatientSatisfaction.DimensionPercentile AS di
INNER JOIN ("
```

Comment: Are you removing or extracting? Please provide expected output.

Comment: I added additional detail about what I'm trying to accomplish.  I can add my entire script if that helps but I thought that might complicate things for answerers. My script works great except that the regex is picking up commas that I want it to ignore.

Comment: Try `(?!^),(?!$)|(.{2},.{2})` and if you have a multiline string (I understand it is), use `oRe.Multiline=True`

Comment: Multiline is already true in my script.  Your suggested pattern is interesting, thank you. The first option is picking up all the commas ... even those not near a line feed/carriage return. But it is giving me some insight. I'll keep working on it. Thanks!

Comment: You can use a negative lookbehind to see if your match is preceded by a `,`. The syntax for this is `(?<!,)(.{2},.{2})`

Comment: @emsimpson92 No, lookbehind is not supported by VBS regex engine.

Comment: Strange... I thought javascript was the only language that didn't support that sort of thing.

Comment: @HeathKat I wish I had the insight, too. Right now, I am still not sure what is required. [My regex](https://regex101.com/r/UzLID0/1) does not match the commas you mentioned.

Comment: VBS flavor of regex is most similar to javascript, so that makes sense.

Comment: @emsimpson92 JavaScript already supports lookbehinds, even infinite-width (try in Chrome that supports ECMAScript 2018)

Comment: Unfortunately your regex  doesn't seem to match anything on my end.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I sure appreciate you considering my question.  I will figure it out sooner or later and will post my solution. You gave me something to think about!

Comment: Then I am voting to close as unclear. You are asking something, and do not provide details.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand. I can post additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are matching the first occurrence only - that is,

`SELECT
 di.QuestionSetID AS SectionID
,`<- here

You're not seeing any effect, though, because you are replacing it with the same text you captured, in doing `"$1$2$3"`.

What you want to do, if you don't want to match the commas around line-spaces, and only replace those in the middle of a line, is not anchor the commas to `[\r\n]`. You can invert it with the caret: `[^\r\n]` so that it matches anything that is NOT `\r` or `\n`. Then, you need to re-structure the pattern accordingly.

`([^\r\n]),([^\n\r])` will match anything that is not \r or \n either side of a comma, and capture those characters in $1 and $2. To replace the comma with a space, your replacement string should therefore be: `"$1 $2"`.

```
SQLScript = "SELECT
 di.QuestionSetID AS SectionID
,di.ScoreNBR AS Section,LowestTopBoxNBR
,di.AveragePercentileNBR AS SectionTopBoxPercentileRankNBR 
,qdate.Quarter,StartDTS AS Section,StartDTS 
FROM NRCPicker.PatientSatisfaction.DimensionPercentile AS di
INNER JOIN ("
oRe.Pattern = "([^\r\n]),([^\n\r])" 
oLoadFields = oRe.Replace(SQLScript, "$1 $2")
```

Comment: This does exactly what I wanted it to do. Thank you! Although all three of the suggested solutions worked when I tested them, I'm going to use this one because I understand how/why it works well enough that I can modify it to adapt to other situations if user needs change.

Answer (score 0):

If VBS uses roughly the same engine that JS uses, then you can
leverage the look ahead assertion and 
BOL/EOL anchors.

In ***multi-line mode*** :

Find `(?!^),(?!$)`
Replace with a space

https://regex101.com/r/LRXNvz/1

***update note:***
*Note that you can't just capture whats to the left and right of the comma,

then write that back
since there could be adjacent sequential commas.

So anything like `(.),(.)`  won't work.*

*Example 1: It matches 'hell`o,,`,,,world' which advances the current position

past the next comma and will never match the second one.*

*Example 2:  It matches 'hello,,`,,,`world' which writes back a comma.

You can see this dysfunction here [https://regex101.com/r/u5CPgb/1](https://regex101.com/r/u5CPgb/1_)*

Comment: @HeathKat - It's the only way it can be done. Added an update note. Clearly you can't just use (.),(.) or anything like that  including the answer you accepted. There are edge cases to consider.

Comment: Hmmm, I will have to look into this more.  Thank you for the additional explanation. I am still trying to understand look aheads. I haven't found sequential commas in any of the SQL scripts I'm parsing but I suppose it's possible they might occur and I'll have to deal with them.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
(\S+?),(?=\S+)
```

We exploit the fact that the `,` in question are always surrounded by non-whitespace `\S`. Since there is no (positive) lookbehind in VBScript's RegExp I simply capture the leading part and put it back while the comma itself is replaced by a space: `"$1 "`.

This also works if there is extra whitespace at the end or beginning of the line.

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/rS9rzH/1)

Code Sample:

```
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "(\S+?),(?=\S+)"
re.Global = True
Dim Input 
Input = "SELECT " & vbCRLF & _
" di.QuestionSetID AS SectionID, " & vbCRLF & _
" di.QuestionSetID AS SectionID2 " & vbCRLF & _
",di.ScoreNBR AS Section,LowestTopBoxNBR" & vbCRLF & _
",di.AveragePercentileNBR AS SectionTopBoxPercentileRankNBR " & vbCRLF & _
",qdate.Quarter,StartDTS AS Section,StartDTS "& vbCRLF & _
"FROM NRCPicker.PatientSatisfaction.DimensionPercentile AS di" & vbCRLF & _
"INNER JOIN ("

msgbox re.Replace(Input, "$1 ")
```

Comment: Yes ... all three solutions worked when I tested them in my script.  I'm using the first one because I understand it the best.  I'm so grateful for the help. I've been working on this comma problem for a while!

Comment: I upvoted but because I am a newbie it said that the upvote will be recorded but it won't show up in the interface. :-(

Comment: Oh I see ... yes, I will remember to upvote again once I have the rep to do it.

Comment: @HeathKat Thanks